# consumir servicio web java con certificados de cliente

Tags: c#, webservice, soap, certificado

agradezco de su colaboración con la siguiente situación. Tengo un proyecto en .Net C# el cual debe consumir un servicio web externo que esta construido en java, para poder consumir el servicio debo adicionar los certificados de cliente (ya los tengo instalados en la máquina), he leido varios artículos pero no he dado como realizarlo, en un ejemplo de java crean un SSLContext donde adicionan los certificados y después los pasan aun HttpPost pero no se con que clases en c# puedo homologar estas de java.

los siguientes son algunos árticulos que he leido.

[Consumo de Servicio web SOAP con certificados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39338/consumo-de-servicio-web-soap-con-certificados)

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-use-separate-x-509-certificates-for-signing-and-encryption

[Firmar Mensaje SOAP con Certificaco X509 c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9863/firmar-mensaje-soap-con-certificaco-x509-c)

https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/01/25/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-5-working-with-client-certificates-in-a-web-project/